# How do I add a span class to form item title in register form?

Tags: 6, forms

```
'#title' => t('I have read and agree to the') . "<b><a href='/terms' target='_blank'> terms of service</a></b>",
```

How do I add a span class to the whole title, so It would end up like so:

```
 <span class="myclass">I have read and agree to the <b><a href='/terms' target='_blank'>terms of service</a></b></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
'#title' => '<span class="myclass">' . t('I have read and agree to the <b><a href="@terms" target="_blank">terms of service</a></b>', array('@terms' => url('terms'))) . '</span>',
```